# Do i need super when creating a subclass or not?

Tags: java, constructor, arguments, super

In this program there is no need for a `super` to reach the superclass's constructor:

```
class Base{

    Base(){

        System.out.println("Base");
    }
}

public class test2 extends Base{

    test2() {

        //super();
        System.out.print("test2"); 
    }

    public static void main(String argv[]){

        test2 c = new test2();
    }    
}
```

But this program needs `super` and gives an error at `quest1` constructor saying

> constructor `quest` can't be applied to given types: required int, found no arguments

```
class Quest {

    Quest(int y){

        System.out.print("A:"+y);
    }
}

class Quest1 extends Quest {

    Quest1(int x){

        //super(x+1); 
        System.out.print("B:"+x);
    }
}

class Test {

    public static void main(String argv[]){

        Quest1 q = new Quest1(5); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Was your question answered?

Comment: @user1803551 i understood when i need super but the answers were confusing when it comes to when we need super. so i didnt choose one.

Comment: Fair enough, but then you should ask for clarifications by the answerers, that's what the comments are for and it's their job to explain the answer and supplement it.

Comment: how about i edit the answer to the end of my post? we use super when we use a method with argument(s) right? if there are no arguments like my first example, we dont use super. But if there are arguments like my 2. example, we use arguments right?

Comment: Don't include others` answers in your question. You can edit your question to make it more clear or add information. About the usage of `super(...)`, you use it in a method to call the the overriden method regardless of the arguments. If there are arguments or not does not affect `super`. You question is specifically about constructors where the rules are different than other "regular" methods, but what I said still holds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> JLS 8.8.7. Constructor Body
>
> > If a constructor body does not begin with an explicit constructor invocation and the constructor being declared is not part of the primordial class `Object`, then the constructor body implicitly begins with a superclass constructor invocation "`super();`", an invocation of the constructor of its direct superclass that takes no arguments.

In

```
class Base {

    Base() {

    }
}

public class test2 extends Base {

    test2() {

        //super();
        System.out.print("test2"); 
    }  
}
```

The commented out line is added automatically and since the superclass's no-argument constructor is defined, there is no error.

In the case of

```
class Quest {

    Quest(int y) {

        System.out.print("A:"+y);
    }
}

class Quest1 extends Quest {

    Quest1(int x) {

        //super(x+1); 
        System.out.print("B:"+x);
    }
}
```

The implicit call `super()` is trying to invoke an undefined constructor in the superclass, which causes the error

> Implicit super constructor Quest() is undefined. Must explicitly invoke another constructor.

Uncommenting your explicit constructor call replaces the implicit call and thus the problem is resolved. Alternatively, define a no-argument constructor in the superclass.

Answer (score 1):

You need a call to `super()` if and only if there's no default constructor (accepting *no arguments*) for your parent `class`.

In all other cases (where a constructor with zero arguments exists) you don#t have to code it. It's implicitly called anyway.

These Rules apply:

- if your parent class **has no constructor at all**, it has the default constructor, which takes no arguments -> no need for `super()`;
- you parent class **declares a constructor with no arguments** -> no need for `super()`
- your class **has a constructor with arguments but *no* constructor without arguments** -> you **need** to call one of the defined constructors with mathching arguments via `super()`

Answer (score -1):

If you create a constructor in super class the you should call the super class constructor (Ex : super()) before the sub class constructor gets call.

Comment: You can't call the super constructor before the subclass constructor gets called. It has to be the first thing you do inside the subclass constructor.

Comment: Yes I'm also tel the same. Pls understand my answer. What you Understood : super(); SubClass obj = new SubClass(); Everyone know this is Worng. My answer is : SubClass{ super(); SubClass(){} }

Comment: Why won't you write it clearly in your answer? As it is written now, it is wrong.

Comment: What I said earlier. It's not *"you should call the super class constructor before the sub class constructor gets call"*, it's *you should call the super class constructor as the first thing in the subclass constructor call*. Even then *should* should be *can* because this is true only if the `super` constructor has arguments.